# Type objects between serializations, given class changes

Tags: c#, serialization, types

I am storing type related information in a dictionary, e.g.

```
Dictionary<Type, int> TypeInformation;

TypeInformation[typeof(OneOfMyOwnClasses)] = 42;
```

Then I (binary) serialize the state of my application, including the above dictionary.

What happens to the type objects **if I change `OneOfMyOwnClasses` in code**? Under which conditions do the type objects stay the same after deserialization? I.e. when will

```
if (TypeInformation[typeof(OneOfMyOwnClasses)] == 42)
    MessageBox.Show("Yahoo !!!");
```

give an affirmative result even after I deserialize the state of my app?

- Is a change of method bodies guaranteed to give the same type objects between different runs?
- Do changes of private method or field names change anything about the type objects?
- Changes of public method (or field) names?
- Change of namespace or assembly?
- Changes of class name itself? (supposedly not... ;-) )

Finally, given all that, are there any good reasons not to serialize type infos and is there a better yet more involved way (like creating GUID's and such)?

Comment: when you say "binary" serialize - do you mean `BinaryFormatter`? (there are many ways to binary serialize something, `BinaryFormatter` is just one way, and usually a very bad choice, frankly; if you are still at a point where you can choose the serializer, I would strongly advocate "not that")

Comment: Yes, BinaryFormatter. The reason being mainly that I wanted to preclude error handling for cases where the user "fiddles" with XML files. I want to change to XML some time in the future, but I would like to postpone this because of things I consider higher priority. But if there is good reason in the given context, I might do it first.

Comment: The type information is a dynamic enumeration (number) that is added by the compiler.  The compiler contains standard type like string, integer, boolean that always give same enumeration.  Custom types like classes are assigned type number by the compiler dynamically.  So any change in the code (adding or deleting classes) can affect the number.   Not sure but type number is probably as hash function but compiler has to check to make sure there are no duplicate values.

Comment: @jdweng when `BinaryFormatter` *serializes* a `Type` instance, it will use the fully-qualified name, not the compiler's internal handle

Comment: Ops code is testing for "== 42" which is a number not a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean `BinaryFormatter`, then:

1. changing the type, namespace, or assembly identity of a type will break the serializer if you are storing instances of the type, or the `Type` object itself
2. changing the names or types of the *fields* on a type will break the serializer, *if you are storing **instances** of that  type*

In both cases there are ways to kinda fix it by jumping through complex hoops, but it usually isn't a good idea to try. In my considered experience, `BinaryFormatter` simply isn't a good choice except in very specific scenarios (in particular, RPC between two running applications that must by necessity be running the exact same code - such as app-domain isolation), and if your intent is general purpose *storage*, you are usually better using **anything else**. My particular leaning is towards protobuf-net (which is "binary" in that it implements google's binary "protocol buffers" format), but I'm admittedly biased. JSON and XML are also good options in terms of portability, although they almost always have larger output and (slightly) slower processing.

Note that *most* serializers, when serializing a `Type` object, will use the fully-qualified name, so point 1 above will apply to most, although per-serializer ways of *changing* that may exist. Frankly, though, I'd say that if you're serializing a `Type` instance, you're *doing something wrong*, and it would be better to do that as a manual keyed lookup against some external reference (which could be via an attribute on the type, for example). For example:

```cs
[SomeMarker("abc")]
class OneOfMyOwnClasses {...}
```

then use reflection to get the `SomeMarkerAttribute` instance (in some cached way), such that you actually store:

```cs
Type type = ...
string key = GetMarkerFromType(type); // "abc"
Dictionary<string, int> TypeInformation;
TypeInformation[key] = 42;
```

Comment: Oops, didn't know that BinaryFormatter is that bad. So your second item explains what constitutes a type change? In short, every change in the interface names and types?

Comment: @oliver I've added an extra paragraph for that; since you're talking about an instance of `Type`, rather than an instance *of the type*, we're really talking about the fully-qualified name here, in most cases.

Comment: I have already noticed a lot of problems due to me changing versions (i.e. the interfaces of the inspected types) frequently. Luckily only for my own purposes yet. So I guess there is no way around changig serialization to XML (as my personal favorite) early.

Comment: By the way, your hint on using attributes to create an ID for classes helps me a lot, because that's what I am already doing! I just did not come to the idea of using the obtained information for serialization as well. Thanks, and happy labour day! :-)